# Continuously test throughout execution

Tags: loops, autoit

My AutoIt script automates a mobile game. Sometimes the game will disconnect (due to an error or bad WiFi signal), causing the script to get off track and stop working correctly. I'm trying to test when/if this occurs, to then restart from the beginning.

```
Func _TestConnection()
    $Continue       = True
    $DisconnectTest = PixelSearch(3146, 760, 3262, 791, 0x125C12, 10) ;search for popup
    If Not (@error) Then
        _LC(3112, 779) ;click Yes to reconnect
        Sleep(10000)
        Return $Continue = False
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

This function will return `False` if an error pop-up is found. However I need to have this checked continuously because it can disconnect at any time.

Even reducing this to one line would help. For example: `If _TestConnection() = False Then ExitLoop`. But this won't return to where it left off; just exits the loop and continues with the rest of the script.

Another useful command would be `If _TestConnection() = False Then Break`, but this stops the program from working altogether.

Comment: What about [AdlibRegister](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AdlibRegister.htm) like `AdlibRegister("_testConnection",2000)`,  which calls the function every two seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want to restart the automation script from the beginning, the easiest way is to have two processes running. The first one launches the automation script, and then without waiting for that to finish, runs the connection testing looping. When the connection fails, terminate the second process, reconnect, and then restart your automation script.